# Class templates that are both base classes and directly usable

Tags: c++, templates, graph-theory

I have two classes representing a graph:

```cpp
class Node {
public:
   void AppendSource(Edge &Edge) { m_Sources.append(&Edge); }
   void AppendSink(Edge &Edge) { m_Sinks.append(&Edge); }
   QList<Edge *> &Sources() { return m_Sources; }
   QList<Edge *> &Sinks() { return m_Sinks; }
   QList<Edge *> const &Sources() const { return m_Sources; }
   QList<Edge *> const &Sinks() const { return m_Sinks; }
protected:
   QList<Edge *> m_Sources;
   QList<Edge *> m_Sinks;
}; // Node

class Edge {
public:
   Edge(Node &Source, Node &Sink) : m_pSource(&Source), m_pSink(&Sink) {}
   Node const &Source() const { return *m_pSource; }
   Node const &Sink() const { return *m_pSink; }
   Node &Source() { return *m_pSource; }
   Node &Sink() { return *m_pSink; }
   void SetSource(Node &Source) { m_pSource = &Source; }
   void SetSink(Node &Sink) { m_pSink = &Sink; }
protected:
   Node *m_pSource;
   Node *m_pSink;
}; // Edge
```

It should be possible to inherit from these classes, in order to add functionality for specific types of graphs. Therefore, the classes should be template classes:

```cpp
template <class EDGE_TYPE>
class Node {
public:
   void AppendSource(EDGE_TYPE &Edge) { m_Sources.append(&Edge); }
   void AppendSink(EDGE_TYPE &Edge) { m_Sinks.append(&Edge); }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> &Sources() { return m_Sources; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> &Sinks() { return m_Sinks; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> const &Sources() const { return m_Sources; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> const &Sinks() const { return m_Sinks; }
protected:
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> m_Sources;
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> m_Sinks;
}; // Node


template <class NODE_TYPE>
class Edge {
public:
   Edge(NODE_TYPE &Source, NODE_TYPE &Sink) : m_pSource(&Source), m_pSink(&Sink) {}
   NODE_TYPE const &Source() const { return *m_pSource; }
   NODE_TYPE const &Sink() const { return *m_pSink; }
   NODE_TYPE &Source() { return *m_pSource; }
   NODE_TYPE &Sink() { return *m_pSink; }
   void SetSource(NODE_TYPE &Source) { m_pSource = &Source; }
   void SetSink(NODE_TYPE &Sink) { m_pSink = &Sink; }
protected:
   NODE_TYPE *m_pSource;
   NODE_TYPE *m_pSink;
}; // Edge
```

But now it seems no longer possible to use the classes without extending them! A few attempts with the obvious corresponding errors:

```cpp
new Node(); // 'Node': use of class template requires template argument list
new Node<>(); // 'Node': too few template arguments
new Node<Edge>(); // 'Edge': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'EDGE_TYPE', expected a real type
new Node<Edge<>>(); // 'Edge': too few template arguments
new Node<Edge<Node>>(); // 'Node': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'NODE_TYPE', expected a real type
new Node<Edge<Node<>>>(); // 'Node': too few template arguments
```

I was hoping to solve this by introducing defaults for the template arguments. A few attempt with their corresponding errors:

```cpp
template <class EDGE_TYPE = Edge>
class Node { ... }

template <class NODE_TYPE = Node>
class Edge { ... }

new Node<>(); // 'Edge': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'EDGE_TYPE', expected a real type
```

```cpp
template <class EDGE_TYPE = Edge<>>
class Node { ... }

template <class NODE_TYPE = Node<>>
class Edge { ... }

new Node<>(); // recursive type or function dependency context too complex
```

```cpp
template <class EDGE_TYPE = Edge<Node<EDGE_TYPE>>>
class Node { ... }


template <class NODE_TYPE = Node<Edge<NODE_TYPE>>>
class Edge { ... }

new Node<>(); // 'EDGE_TYPE': undeclared identifier
```

How can I make `Node` and `Edge` both directly usable and extensible though inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make Node and Edge both **directly usable** and extensible
>   though inheritance?

I'll focus on that requirement in bold.

Though you can have the *definition* of Edge and Node depend on each other, there's no way to make recurring *declaration* of Edge and Node, because such declaration would yield infinite template recursion:

```
Node<> = Node<Edge<>> = Node<Edge<Node<>>> = Node<EdgeNode<Edge<>>>> ...
```

So, if you want `Edge<>` and `Node<>` to be directly usable (i.e. instantiateable without making dummy derived classes), then you should break that recursion. For example, by making both `Edge` and `Node` depend on some third traits class:

```
// Forward declaration.
struct DefaultGraphTypes;

template <typename GraphTypes = DefaultGraphTypes>
struct Node;

template <typename GraphTypes = DefaultGraphTypes>
struct Edge;


// Traits class.
template <typename NodeT, typename EdgeT>
struct GraphTypes
{
    // Could change this to 'using' in modern C++
    typedef NodeT   FinalNodeType;
    typedef EdgeT   FinalEdgeType;

    // typedef MayBeSomeOtherParameters ...
};

struct DefaultGraphTypes
 : public GraphTypes<Node<DefaultGraphTypes>, Edge<DefaultGraphTypes>>
{
};


// Implementation of graph classes.
template <typename GraphTypes>
struct Node
{
    typedef typename GraphTypes::FinalNodeType    FinalNodeType;
    typedef typename GraphTypes::FinalEdgeType    FinalEdgeType;

    // ... Your implementation
};

template <typename GraphTypes>
struct Edge
{
    typedef typename GraphTypes::FinalNodeType    FinalNodeType;
    typedef typename GraphTypes::FinalEdgeType    FinalEdgeType;

    // ... Your implementation
};


//  User-derived types.
struct MyNode;
struct MyEdge;

struct MyNode
 : public Node<GraphTypes<MyNode, MyEdge>>
{
    // Something specific
};

struct MyEdge
 : public Edge<GraphTypes<MyNode, MyEdge>>
{
    // Something specific
};


// Test
int main()
{
    Node<>       n1;
    Edge<>       e1;

    MyNode       n2;
    MyEdge       e2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice the trick to avoid recursivity for GraphTypes by introducing child `DefaultGraphTypes`.

Comment: @Jarod42, right! Perhaps I misunderstood your point, but that trick isn't the key here, for `DefaultGraphTypes` could be defined in any way of OP's choice, provided it has those member types `FinalNodeType` and `FinalEdgeType` exposed. That trick just allowed to reuse the generic traits, saving me a few copy-paste lines.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this can be achieved by inserting forward declarations at the right place. I took parts of OP sample code and completed it to a compilable sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define QList std::vector // Sorry, no Qt at hand in coliru

template <class EDGE_TYPE>
class Node {
public:
   void AppendSource(EDGE_TYPE &Edge) { m_Sources.append(&Edge); }
   void AppendSink(EDGE_TYPE &Edge) { m_Sinks.append(&Edge); }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> &Sources() { return m_Sources; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> &Sinks() { return m_Sinks; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> const &Sources() const { return m_Sources; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> const &Sinks() const { return m_Sinks; }
protected:
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> m_Sources;
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> m_Sinks;
}; // Node


template <class NODE_TYPE>
class Edge {
public:
   Edge(NODE_TYPE &Source, NODE_TYPE &Sink) : m_pSource(&Source), m_pSink(&Sink) {}
   NODE_TYPE const &Source() const { return *m_pSource; }
   NODE_TYPE const &Sink() const { return *m_pSink; }
   NODE_TYPE &Source() { return *m_pSource; }
   NODE_TYPE &Sink() { return *m_pSink; }
   void SetSource(NODE_TYPE &Source) { m_pSource = &Source; }
   void SetSink(NODE_TYPE &Sink) { m_pSink = &Sink; }
protected:
   NODE_TYPE *m_pSource;
   NODE_TYPE *m_pSink;
}; // Edge

// forward declarations:
struct WNode;
struct WEdge;

// declaration of derived types

struct WNode: public Node<WEdge>
{
  int weight;
};

struct WEdge: public Edge<WNode>
{
  int weight;
  WEdge(WNode &src, WNode &snk): Edge(src, snk) { }
};

// check whether it compiles

int main()
{
  WNode node1, node2;
  WEdge edge12(node1, node2);
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaca5e0207f3d8cf)</kbd>

That's the actual trick:

OP carefully used in `template class Node` and `template class Edge` only references and pointers to the resp. opposite type. Hence, an incomplete type is fully sufficient to be used as template argument in both cases. These incomplete types are provided by the forward declarations:

```
// forward declarations:
struct WNode;
struct WEdge;
```

Afterwards, the classes `WNode` and `WEdge` can be derived from `Node<WEdge>` and `Edge<WNode>`.

Comment: Thanks. This make the classes usable through inheritance, but not directly usable, as in `new Node<>();`.

Comment: It seems that I somehow missed the _directly usable_ but you already have an accepted answer... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

template template parameter might help:

```
template <typename TEdge>
class Node {
public:
   using EDGE_TYPE = TEdge;

   void AppendSource(EDGE_TYPE &Edge) { m_Sources.append(&Edge); }
   void AppendSink(EDGE_TYPE &Edge) { m_Sinks.append(&Edge); }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> &Sources() { return m_Sources; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> &Sinks() { return m_Sinks; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> const &Sources() const { return m_Sources; }
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> const &Sinks() const { return m_Sinks; }
protected:
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> m_Sources;
   QList<EDGE_TYPE *> m_Sinks;
}; // Node

template <template <typename> class TNode>
class Edge {
public:
    using NODE_TYPE = TNode<Edge>; // which is TNode<Edge<TNode>>

    Edge(NODE_TYPE &Source, NODE_TYPE &Sink) : m_pSource(&Source), m_pSink(&Sink) {}
    NODE_TYPE const &Source() const { return *m_pSource; }
    NODE_TYPE const &Sink() const { return *m_pSink; }
    NODE_TYPE &Source() { return *m_pSource; }
    NODE_TYPE &Sink() { return *m_pSink; }
    void SetSource(NODE_TYPE &Source) { m_pSource = &Source; }
    void SetSink(NODE_TYPE &Sink) { m_pSink = &Sink; }
protected:
    NODE_TYPE *m_pSource;
    NODE_TYPE *m_pSink;
};
```

Then you might have:

```
using MyEdge = Edge<Node>;
using MyNode = Node<Edge<Node>>; // Node<MyEdge>
```

or even:

```
template <template <typename> class TNode>
class CustomEdge : Edge<TNode> {
    // ...
};

using MyNode2 = Node<CustomEdge>;
using MyEdge2 = CustomEdge<Node>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dac0e0f8dd1134a7)

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, but when doing `using MyNode = Node<Edge>;`, I get an error: `error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'Edge' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'TEdge'`. There are similar errors for the other `using` statements.

Comment: @MagnarMyrtveit: indeed, some error. one have to use typename whereas the other need template template parameter (So no longer symmetrical). Code fixed, and Demo added.